# Database Architecture (Help)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Am i doing this correctly? I know it's super simply, but I am just now getting some DBA experience.

I have an Entity Table that is non static called Emps. The Emps table stores all the Employee personal information like phone numbers and so on. I then have a table called EmployeeOfflineTraining. This Table stores all Employees who are certified in Classroom training like Forklift.

Do i simply put a foreign key inside the EmployeeOfflineTraining table to assign training records to that employee ID?

Emps
(Phone, Agency, Name)

EmployeeOffLineTraining
(GpcScore, Forklift Score, ForklifeCertified, EmpsId)

Comment: That's how I would do it.   BTW the WROX book on database design is excellent.

Comment: For the question at hand yes. But your EmployeeOffLineTraining table has some problems. You don't want columns for ForkliftScore and such. You would want to have a table of training classes and an intermediate table to track which employees took which classes. Think how crazy your table would get if you have 100 class options.

Comment: @SeanLange So I should use a Junction Table? I should have a Table of (Emps) (TrainingCompleted - OfflineTrainingId,EmpsId) (OfflineTrainingCertfications) and use like a Boolean for a simple True or False type thing?

Comment: Yes that would be a better design than columns for each type of training. See the idea from Explosion Pills below. That pretty much nails it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an indirection table that maps TrainingId to EmployeeOfflineTraining as well. This gives you flexibility in case you need to introduce multiple training types -- you can simply add a row to the Training table rather than having to alter the EmployeeOFflineTraining table.

You may also consider creating an `Agency` and `EmployeeAgency` table as well in the same vein.

```
CREATE TABLE Emps (
  empId int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  phone varchar(255),
  agency varchar(255),
  name varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Training (
  trainingId int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE EmployeeOfflineTraining (
  eotId int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  empId int unsigned not null,
  trainingId int unsigned not null,
  score smallint unsigned,
  certifiedDate datetime,
  foreign key (empId) references Emps(empId),
  foreign key (trainingId) references Training(trainingId)
);
```

Comment: Hey, explosion, if I did it that way, how would I design in the completion date, letter grade, and number grade that each employee has for each trainingId?

Comment: I have those as `certifiedDate` and `score`.

Comment: In the Training table?

Training
(Tugger, Forklift, Sps, TuggerCompletionDate, Forklift CompletetionDate, SpsLetterScore, SpsNumScore) 

Like this? (Just examples)

Comment: No in the indirection table

Comment: Thanks Explosion!

Comment: Hey, Explosion, one final questions. I would still have to create a ForkliftCertDate, TuggerCertDate,SpsCertDate, SpsLetterScore, SpsNumericalScore). Within the table right? I need dates / scores for each of the certifications.

Comment: No, the idea is that you will have `Forklift`, `Tugger`, `Sps`, etc. as rows in the `Training` column. This allows you to have a row for each certificate type which will have a corresponding certification date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.[Wikipedia Entry On DB Normilzation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) What you are looking for is called Databse Normilzation

### Employees

EmployeeID  PrimaryKey

Phone

EmployeeName

AgencyId

### Agencies

AgencyId  PrimaryKey

AgencyName

### EmployeeOfflineTraining

EMployeeOfflineTrainingId PrimaryKey

EmployeeId                ForiegnKey to Employee Table

GpcSocre

ForkliftScore

ForkliftCertified

***Edit***
As pointed out be Sean Lange The OfflineTraining Table has major problems which are not addressed in this answer.